# Estimate for the fundamental solution of Laplace equation from Evans

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, estimation, hessian-matrix

After the definition of the *fundamental solution* of Laplace 
equation (page 22)

$\Phi(x) = \begin{cases} -\frac{1}{2\pi} \, \log(|x|), \, & n=2, \\ \frac{1}{n \, (n-2) \, \omega_n} \, \frac{1}{|x|^{n-2}}, \, & n\geq 3, \end{cases}$

Evans gives two estimates:

(i) $|D \Phi(x)| \leq \frac{C}{|x|^{n-1}}$

**(ii)** $|D^2 \Phi(x)|\leq \frac{C}{|x|^n}$

for some constant $C>0$

I have been able to prove (i) with no difficulties, but I'm really stuck on **(ii)**, **for the case n \leq 3**.

---

I know that $D^2 \Phi(x)$ denotes the hessian matrix of $\Phi$, but I don't understand how to compute its norm. As far as I know (I looked up on the appendix), given a matrix $A$, Evans writes
\begin{align}
|A|=(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2)^{1/2} \quad \star
\end{align}

So I write in the following the $(i,j)$-th element of $D\Phi(x)$

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j} [\frac{\partial \Phi(x)}{\partial x_i}]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}[v'(|x|) \frac{x_i}{|x|}]=v''(|x|) \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^2} - v'(|x|) \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^3}
\end{align}

Now I plug in the definition of $v(|x|)=C |x|^{1-N}$, $C$ constant, hence I have that

\begin{align}
(D \Phi(x))_{ij}=C(1-N) \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^{2+N}}-C \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^{2+N}} = -N \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^{2+N}}
\end{align}

Now I should just apply $\star$, but I don't know how to move from here

**EDIT**

I have that $(D \Phi(x))_{ij}=-N \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^{2+N}}\leq -N \frac{|x|^2}{|x|^{2+N}}=-N \frac{1}{|x|^N}$

and since this bound does not depend on $(i,j)$ anymore I apply straightforward $\star$ and get

\begin{align}
\frac{N}{|x|^N} \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^{N}}1 =\frac{N^2}{|x|^N} 
\end{align}

and hence I have the desired bound

**EDIT$^2$** [17/5/2019]

After the comments with @SeverinSchraven, differentiating I end up with

\begin{align} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[v'(|x|) \frac{x_i}{|x|}]= \ldots=\frac{C}{|x|^N}-N \frac{x_i^2}{|x|^{N+2}} \end{align}

and so I have, in the Hessian matrix:

\begin{equation} a_{ij}=
\begin{cases}
\frac{N}{|x|^N} \quad i \ne j \\
\frac{(C-N)}{|x|^N} \quad i =j 
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

So, using $\star$ I have:

$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sum_{j=1}^{N} a_{ij}^2}= \sqrt{\sum_{i} \sum_{i} a_{ii}^2 + \frac{N^2}{|x|^N}}=\sqrt{\frac{1}{|x|^{2N}}(N^2+(N^2(C-N)^2)}=\frac{N}{|x|^N} \cdot \tilde{C}$, where $\tilde{C}=\sqrt{1+(C-N)^2}$

Comment: Note that $x_i x_j \leq x_i^2 + x_j^2 \leq \vert x \vert^2$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven could it be okay now?

Comment: You should take absolute value. Otherwise you are in trouble due to the minus sign.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven You're right! I took it, but since $N>0$ I did not wrote it! Finally, I can say that $|D^2 \Phi| \leq \frac{N^2}{|x|^N}$, and the constant depends on $N$. Do you think it's right? I mean, the book just writes $C$

Comment: I would guess that it depends on $N$. What is is more important, you need also to consider the case $i=j$, which you omitted so far.

Comment: When you differentiate with respect to $j$, then you need to differentiate $\frac{x_i}{\vert x \vert}$. Before you just differentiated the absolute value (which is fine when $i\neq j$), however, you need to use the product rule once more if $i=j$.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Ups, you're totally right. After computations, I end up with \begin{align} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[v'(|x|) \frac{x_i}{|x|}]= \ldots=\frac{C}{|x|^N}-N \frac{x_i^2}{|x|^{N+2}} \end{align}

Summing this over $i$, I get $(C-N)\frac{1}{|x|^N}$

What is left is to write explicitely the norm of the hessian matrix, I think I need  distinguish the two cases $i=j, i \ne j$ in the $\star$ sum, but how?

Comment: You can use the triangle inequality and the fact that $x_i^2 \leq \vert x \vert^2$

Comment: just edited my original post is it okay now?

Comment: I would suggest you to write an answer yourself. While writing down the details things will become much clearer. We can still comment in case you make a minor mistake.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven I posted my answer, it nobody said anything, so I assume it's okay

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After the comments, I'll write an answer.

Evans defines $|A|$, where $A$ is a matrix, as

\begin{align}
|A|=(\sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2)^{1/2} \quad \star
\end{align}

so, in order to compute the norm of $D^2 \Phi$ (Hessian matrix), I need to compute each component $a_{ij}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}(\frac{\partial \Phi(x)}{\partial x_j})$

As pointed out in comments, I need to distinguish the case $i=j$ and $i \ne j$. [Recall that in Evans $v'(|x|)=v'(r)=C r^{1-N}$ ]

---

So, for $i \ne j$:

$ \frac{\partial}{\partial x_i} [\frac{\partial \Phi(x)}{\partial x_j}]=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[v'(|x|) \frac{x_j}{|x|}]=v''(|x|) \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^2} - v'(|x|) \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^3} $

Pluggin in the definition of $v(|x|)$:

\begin{align}
a_{ij}= -N \frac{x_i x_j}{|x|^{2+N}}, \quad i \ne j
\end{align}

---

In the case $i=j$ I have:

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}[v'(|x|) \frac{x_i}{|x|}]=v''(|x|) \frac{x_i^2}{|x|^2} + v'(|x|) [ \frac{1}{|x|^2} - \frac{x_i^2}{|x|^3}]=C(1-N) \frac{x_i^2}{|x|^{N+2}}+\frac{C}{|x|^N}-C \frac{x_i^2}{|x|^{N+2}}$

So,

\begin{align}
a_{ij}=
\frac{C}{|x|^N}-NC \frac{x_i^2}{|x|^{N+2}}, \quad i =j
\end{align}

---

In order to compute $\star$, I use that $x_i^2 \leq |x|^2$ and so I can *bound* $a_{ii}$ in the following way

$a_{ii} \leq \frac{C}{|x|^N}+NC \frac{|x|^2}{|x|^{N+2}}=C(1+N) \frac{1}{|x|^N}$

So,
\begin{align}
\sum_i \sum _i a_{ii}^2 \leq N^2 C^2(1+N)^2 \frac{1}{|x|^{2N}}
\end{align}

Now, bounding again $a_{ij}$ ($i \ne j$) by using the fact that $x_i x_j \leq |x|^2$, I have

\begin{align}
\sum_i \sum_j a_{ij}^2 \leq \sum_i \sum_j (\frac{N}{|x|^{N}})^2=N(N-1)N^2 \frac{1}{|x|^{2N}} 
\end{align}

Now I put together the two sums and get

\begin{align}
\frac{N^2}{|x|^{2N}} [N(N-1)+C^2(1+N)^2]
\end{align}

hence, by taking the square root:

$|D^2 \Phi(x)| \leq \frac{N}{|x|^N} \sqrt{N(N-1)+C^2(1+N)^2}=\tilde{C} \frac{N}{|x|^N}$

where $\tilde{C}=\sqrt{N(N-1)+C^2(N+1)}$

and the bound is proved.